# Запись данных на sdcard в Android

Tags: android, storage

Помогите разобраться. Пытаюсь просто создать папку с подпапками в корне sdcard.

```
new File(path).mkdirs();
```

path - /storage/sdcard1/GetGeo/backups/160516164519

mkdirs всегда возвращает false (папка не создаётся)

в манифесте прописал

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

скрин того, что выдаёт adbshell
[image: скрин того, что выдаёт adbshell]

через него я могу создать папку
[image: через adbshell я могу создать папку]

Помогите разобраться

- почему может не работать
- как решить проблему

Аналогичный алгоритм с path - /storage/sdcard0/GetGeo/backups/160516164519 (т.е. внутренней памятью) работает (т.е. все папки и подпапки создаются)

На руках пока два девайса 5.1.1 и 5.1 и на обоих проблема. Известно про requestpermissions на 6+. Пока проверял только на android ниже 6

Comment: Попробуйте new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test-folder").mkdirs(); Вот так создать просто в корне папку test-folder. Получится?

Comment: @Андроид Андроид
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() возвращает всегда /storage/sdcard0
Именно 0 т.е. внутреннюю память, а мне необходимо точно писать на sdcard если она есть или не писать вообще (такая задача).
Итак в /storage/sdcard0 я могу создавать новые папки (это уточнение есть в теле вопроса).
Т.е. код new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test-folder").mkdirs();  выполнится успешно в моём случае (в ответ на ваш вопрос), но это не решит мою проблему

Answer (score 1):

Подытожил для себя пока что так:

Я могу писать в private на sdcard,
например `/storage/sdcard1/Android/data/my.awesome.package/`,но в корень карты пока не могу

Актуально для устройств с андроид 5+

**Обновление:** оказалось в private могу писать только на некоторых девайсах
например на Xperia c4 не могу создать папку по private пути на флешке

**Обновление2:** по неизвестным причинам с проблемой на Xperia c4 помогла перезагрузка телефона О_о